# I’m having trouble solving this digital circuit. Help!

Tags: digital-logic, counter, sequential-logic

I need to design sequential logic circuit from this state diagram using only 2 D-latches.[image]

And this is my attempt:
[image]

If I put it in the simulator it just gives me error and wont count. I assumed that its supposed to be synchronous. I reversed Q1 and Q0 in the state diagram but that isnt supposed to change anything.

I just don’t know where the mistake is. Someone help please.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @winny Nope im just studying and came upon this problem.

Comment: For me, your solution seems to be OK. However, if you build a circuit like in the drawing, you will need some resistors to limit the current through the LEDs.

Comment: Seconding @StefanWyss; that's probably where your simulator is throwing an error too. If there's nothing limiting the current through the LEDs it may well be encountering arithmetic overflow trying to compute the current.

Comment: Another possibility, the simulator may start flopflips in the undefined state, which will never propagate. Maybe a reset is needed to get them all to valid states at the start of the simulation (not essential for a counter in real life).